# Auto-increase number on top of receipt design

Tags: images

I have made a receipt layout in Photoshop, I need to increase the number at the top of each receipt saving out 100 unique images. I can put 4 receipts on each A4 sheet.

I have no idea what to use to do this, can Microsoft Word do it? What is the best software to automatically increase the number placed over the top of the image for each page. So Page 1: 1,2,3,4. Page 2: 5,6,7,8. etc.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations, please add more requirements including what OS this would run on, gratis or commercial, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this sort of thing quite simply with [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) see the examples section on text operations [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/).  Note that you could even have it use the same font provided it is installed on your machine.

- Free
- Cross-Platform
- Swiss Army Knife of Image Manipulation
- Command line interface so can be put into bash scripts, bat files, etc., for the next time you need to do it.